# How to access spring session bean scope in thymeleaf

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have define my object

```java
  @Component
  @Scope(value = "session", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS) 
  public class MySession {
      private String message;

     // getter setter
  }
```

When I try to access from thymeleaf it failed.

```html
<p th:text="${mySession.message}"></p>
```

**SOLUTION**

Accessing through spring beans

http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/springmvcaccessdata.html

```html
 <p th:text="${@mySession.getMessage()}"></p>
```

Comment: what is failing? any error?

Comment: error message: Property or field 'message' cannot be found on null. but, I found the solution, accessing through spring beans

Answer (score 0):

```
session.setAttribute("mySessionAttribute", "someValue");
```

You can access direct session attribute .

```
${#session.getAttribute('mySessionAttribute')}
```

Answer (score 0):

For example the session bean

```
@Component
@SessionScope
public class State implements Serializable {

    private String pdfPropertyName;

    public String getPdfPropertyName() {
        return pdfPropertyName;
    }
    public void setPdfPropertyName(String pdfPropertyName) {
        this.pdfPropertyName = pdfPropertyName;
    }
}
```

In the Controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("uploadPdf")
public class UploadPdfController {

    @Autowired State state;

    @ModelAttribute("pdfPropertyName")
    public String getPdfPropertyName() {
        return state.getPdfPropertyName();
    }

}
```

Can be accessed via

```
<span th:text="${pdfPropertyName}"></span>
```