# Use Thymeleaf to access session scoped proxy bean

Tags: spring, session, thymeleaf

I defined my session scoped proxy bean as below:

```
@Configuration
public class SessionScopeBeans {
    @Bean
    @SessionScope
    public User user() {
        return new User();
    }
}
```

and then inject it into controller:

```
@Controller
public class MyController {
    User user;
...
```

I tried all solutions I found:

```
// fail in Bean way but I don't know why
<span th:text="${@user.getName()}"></span>

// definitely fail because it doesn't relate to sessionAttribute
<span th:text="${session.user.name}"></span>
<span th:text="${#session.user.name}"></span>
```

I don't want to use sessionAttribute because I don't want to change controller method signiture. What can I do?

In question [How to access spring session bean scope in thymeleaf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41380241/how-to-access-spring-session-bean-scope-in-thymeleaf) , question owner said that he can access via bean way but I failed. Is it because of the way I define and inject my bean?

**EDIT**

I removed `@Resource(name = "user")` because I found that is not necessary for injecting User to my controller.

The error is:

```
2020-06-22 15:43:31.092 ERROR 17124 --- [nio-8083-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/home.html]")] with root cause

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot create a session after the response has been committed
```

I found some discussion about this error but they all related to spring-security or spring-session. I didn't use these two modules!!

**EDIT 2**

After some code changes with no brain, suddenly I found `<span th:text="${@user}"></span>` can print out my class instance as string!! No matter how I inject my User bean: @Resource, @Autowired, or even no wiring annotation!! But, `<span th:text="${@user.getName()}"></span>` print nothing when I am sure it has value in it. A little step forward but block again...=(

**EDIT 3**

Finally, I found the stupid thing I did! Below is my controller and I assign user object to another one returned from DAO. So I have 2 user objects, one is controlled by Spring, wired into controller as a session scope bean which is all blank and another is created by DAO as a local variable in controller which contains information. Thymeleaf get the wired one...

```java
@Autowired
private User user;

@PostMapping("/signin")
public String signin(@RequestParam String account, @RequestParam String password, Model model) {
    user = dao.getUser(account);
    return "redirect:/home";
}

@GetMapping("/home")
public String home(Model model) {
    System.out.println(user.getTel());
    return "home";
}
```